# Azure nuget installer and nuget Restore fails in pipeline running in a new machine agent

Tags: azure, certificate, pipeline, nuget-package-restore

I have installed a new Azure agent in a new machine.

I have tried the following pipeline
[image: Pipeline with Nuget installer and nuget restore]

I have problems wit the Use Nuget showing the next error: **Unable to get local issuer Certificate**
[image: Unable to get local issuer Certificate]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install in the new machine the proper SDKs. I have to install all following SDKs.
[image: SDKs needed to run nuget install and nuget restore]

The correct SDK versions depends on your project.